# .NET Core: Generating debuggable assembly from text files in runtime

Tags: .net, .net-core, reflection.emit

Using the TickSpec project (https://github.com/fsprojects/TickSpec), it is possible to execute tests written in gherkin. The gherkin is written in a text file and during runtime the file is loaded and individual rows are mapped to method calls. Using .NET framework the project supports placing breakpoints in the gherkin file. It is implemented using `System.Reflection.Emit` where the ability for the breakpoints (and to have steps in callstack) are added using `MarkSequencePoint` method.

In .NET core the `System.Reflection.Emit` is limited and several methods are missing. I have found that for example the `MarkSequencePoint` method is available in the compiler services. However, I have not found a way how it can be used to emit a dynamic method.

What is the proper way to do such task in netstandard library? I do not necessarily need to emit everything, I need any way how to enable the breakpoints and to have the steps visible in the callstack.

Comment: Have you learnt anything new since asking?

Answer (score 0):

`MarkSequencePoint` for `System.Reflection.Emit` is still not implemented in  .NET 6.0. F# fsi is facing the same issue, they have the ticket https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/5457. Nevertheless, they found a way how to solve the issue, see the pull request https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/12722, the same solution uses C# Interactive.